# AspectJ on servlet using Tomcat ..no errors, no output

Tags: tomcat, servlets, aspectj

I am trying to instrument a servlet so am writing a test code to see if the AspectJ code works on Tomcat.
My Aspect code is as below

```
    @Aspect
public class MonitorAspect {

    @Before("call (* com.rx.ns.adapter.SampleServlet.doPost(..))")
    public void beforePrintlnCall() {
        System.out.println("invoked");
    }
```

The aop.xml is read without an error as, I can see the below logs on tomcat startup. But even after this, the aspectCode is not invoked. I'm trying to trigger a doGet of a servlet code. Is there anymore logs that I can enable to see what is happening ?

> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
>   [WebappClassLoader@538540a3] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.9 built
>   on Monday Mar 14, 2016 at 21:18:16 GMT [WebappClassLoader@538540a3]
>   info register classloader
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader@538540a3
>   [WebappClassLoader@538540a3] info using configuration
>   /C:/Users/lcheeran/workspaceluna/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/TestAspectWeblogic/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
>   [WebappClassLoader@538540a3] info register aspect
>   com.rx.ns.adapter.monitor.MonitorAspect

Comment: Some observations: (1) You want to intercept `doGet`, but the pointcut concerns `doPost`. (2) Even so, it is a `call` pointcut; so you need access to the caller class to weave it. The caller of `doPost()` (or `doGet()`) is the container, which means that you should weave the classes of the container, which you probably haven't. Maybe changing the pointcut to `execution` will help.

Comment: Thank You ! ..I was using doPost all along..I goofed up while writing here .. changing from 'call' to 'execution' helped. A big thank you once again.